# Varying pixel color value for same

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, webgl

I am trying to create an interactive map in webgl . Each counrty in the map image is filled with unique color. When the user clicks on the image, I read the pixeldata iof the point clicked using readPixels() and depending on the color of the pixel I intend to highlight the counrty. But Clicking on the same country returns slightly different color everytime leading to incorrect info about the country clicked.

How do I eliminate the error in finding the exact color of the point on image, user clicked? Are shadowing effects or lighting positions causing this problem?
Or is there a different approach to identify where the user clicked on the image and which country it corresponds to?

```
 var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('map_indexed.png');
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: texture});

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(globeRadius, globeRadius, globeRadius),material);
sphere.overdraw = true;
scene.add(sphere);
```

Reading the pixel data

```
 var x = e.pageX ;
            var y = e.pageY ;
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');


            var gl = renderer.getContext();

            //read the pixel under the mouse from the texture

            var pixelBuffer = new Uint8Array( 4 );

            var xp=gl.readPixels( x, y, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer );
```

Comment: @mplungjan added the parts of relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, shadowing/lighting effects may change the color. Try to use the MeshBasicMaterial material instead of MeshLambertMaterial and see if it helps (MeshBasicMaterial does not need lights in your scene).